# Problem installing any package

Tags: clearpath, turtlebot, jackal, 3rd-party-package, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I am a newbie to ROS. Please bear with me.

Edit 1: I am unable to install any package now. I tried installing Turtlebot Simulator and I am getting the same error. I think there is some problem with ROS itself.

I am unable to install jackal simulator from clearpathrobotics. I get the following error -

E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-jackal-simulator
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-jackal-desktop

I am not sure why this is happening as I have ROS Indigo installed and running Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.
I tried the installation after sudo-apt-get-update, and still I get the same error.

Can anyone please tell why I am unable to install?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224292/problem-installing-any-package/) by [Srinidhi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25631/srinidhi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2016-01-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-17**:
Did you install ROS through apt-get? Are you using ARM or x86?

**Comment by [Srinidhi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25631/srinidhi/) on 2016-01-17**:
Thru apt-get

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-17**:
Have you modified your /etc/apt/sources.list or any of the files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ since you installed ROS?

**Comment by [Srinidhi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25631/srinidhi/) on 2016-01-21**:
No. I have not modified the sources.list file. And there are no files in sources.list.d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using apt-get to install ROS packages assumes that you've installed ROS through apt.

Step 1.2 in the [Jade for Ubuntu installation instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Ubuntu) should create a file called `ros-latest.list` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. This is the sources file which tells apt where to find and download the ROS packages.

If that file doesn't exist, you need to repeat steps 1.2 and 1.3, and then run `sudo apt-get update`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Srinidhi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25631/srinidhi/) on 2016-01-22**:
Thank you very much! This fixed my problem. I am not sure why this happened. I was able to install the beginner tutorials without any problem though. Anyway, thanks again.